# Convert from MAC to IPv6

Tags: ipv6

I would like to understand how to convert a MAC adress to IPv6.
For example:
    00:01:04:76:2A:5C
Should become 
    FE80::0201:04FF:FE76:2A5C

Could someone elaborate the conversion please ?
We suppose an automatic configuration without random parameter for a local machin.

Comment: Take a look at [Modified EUI-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Conversion step by step](http://ben.akrin.com/?p=1347) from a MAC address (48 bits) to a IPv6 address (128 bits):

1. take the mac address: 52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f
2. throw ff:fe in the middle: 52:74:f2:ff:fe:b1:a8:7f
3. reformat to IPv6 notation 5274:f2ff:feb1:a87f
4. convert the first octet from hexadecimal to binary: 52 -> 01010010
5. invert the bit at index 6 (counting from 0): 01010010 -> 01010000
6. convert octet back to hexadecimal: 01010000 -> 50
7. replace first octet with newly calculated one: 5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f
8. prepend the link-local prefix: fe80::5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f

Comment: Actually, the U/L bit needs to be set, but your example clears the bit. This is explained in [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Appendix A: Creating Modified EUI-64 Format Interface Identifiers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#page-20) that show the U/L bit needs to be set to `1` to show a locally derived EUI-64 address.

Answer (score 5):

Bash/zsh function (now working without bc):

```
format_eui_64() {
    local macaddr="$1"
    printf "%02x%s" $(( 16#${macaddr:0:2} ^ 2#00000010 )) "${macaddr:2}" \
        | sed -E -e 's/([0-9a-zA-Z]{2})*/0x\0|/g' \
        | tr -d ':\n' \
        | xargs -d '|' \
        printf "%02x%02x:%02xff:fe%02x:%02x%02x"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of 'bc -v'? 
I get the correct result on my system and could not reproduce your finding yet.

Comment: Oh, I see! The problem was that I've been using zsh and not bash in all test cases and I wasn't aware that bash interprets any leading zero in an arithmetic expression as an octal value. For example `let "i = 010"; echo $i` in bash returns `8` while the same expression in zsh returns `10`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in C. Suggestions are welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int toogle_kth_bit(unsigned int n, int k) { 
    return (n ^ (1 << (k-1))); 
}

/*
- take the mac address: 52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f
- throw ff:fe in the middle: 52:74:f2:ff:fe:b1:a8:7f
- reformat to IPv6 notation 5274:f2ff:feb1:a87f
- convert the first octet from hexadecimal to binary: 52 -> 01010010
- invert the bit at index 6 (counting from 0): 01010010 -> 01010000
- convert octet back to hexadecimal: 01010000 -> 50
- replace first octet with newly calculated one: 5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f
- prepend the link-local prefix: fe80::5074:f2ff:feb1:a87f
*/

void mac_to_ipv6_link_local(char* mac) {
    char mac_c[128];
    char mac_c_exp[128];
    char ipv6[128];
    char ipv6_link_local[128];
    char delim[] = ":";
    int count = 0;

    // throw ff:fe in the middle

    snprintf(mac_c, sizeof(mac_c), "%s", mac);
    char *ptr = strtok(mac_c, delim);

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        count++;

        if (count > 1) {
            snprintf(mac_c_exp, sizeof(mac_c_exp), "%s:%s", mac_c_exp, ptr);
        } else {
            snprintf(mac_c_exp, sizeof(mac_c_exp), "%s%s", mac_c_exp, ptr);
        }

        if (count == 3) {
            snprintf(mac_c_exp, sizeof(mac_c_exp), "%s:%s", mac_c_exp, "ff:fe");
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    // reformat to IPv6 notation

    ptr = strtok(mac_c_exp, delim);
    count = 0;

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        count++;

        if (count % 2 != 0 && count > 1) {
            snprintf(ipv6, sizeof(ipv6), "%s:%s", ipv6, ptr);
        } else {
            snprintf(ipv6, sizeof(ipv6), "%s%s", ipv6, ptr);
        }

        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    // convert the first octet from hexadecimal to binary

    char hex[2] = {ipv6[0], ipv6[1]};
    char inverted_hex[3];
    unsigned int number = (unsigned int)strtol(hex, NULL, 16);

    // invert the bit at index 6 (counting from 0)

    unsigned int new_num = toogle_kth_bit(number, 2);
    sprintf(inverted_hex, "%x", new_num);

    // replace first octet with newly calculated one

    ipv6[0] = inverted_hex[0];
    ipv6[1] = inverted_hex[1];

    // prepend the link-local prefix

    sprintf(ipv6_link_local, "%s%s", "fe80::", ipv6);
    printf("%s\n", ipv6_link_local);
}

int main() {
   mac_to_ipv6_link_local("52:74:f2:b1:a8:7f");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My C# solution or the conversion:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace mac2ipv6
{
    class Program
    {
        static string mac = "52:74:f2:b1:a8:f7";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Remove ':' and '-' from input mac
            string bare_mac = Regex.Replace(mac, "[:-]", String.Empty);

            // Insert fffe in the middle
            bare_mac = bare_mac.Insert(6, "fffe");

            // XOR first octet with 00000010
            int first_octet = Convert.ToInt32(bare_mac.Substring(0, 2), 16);
            int mask = 2;
            int new_first_octet= first_octet ^ mask;
            string new_first_octet_hex = new_first_octet.ToString("X");

            // Replace first octet
            bare_mac = new_first_octet_hex + bare_mac.Substring(2);

            // Prepend link local prefix and format ipv6
            string ipv6 = ("fe80::" + Regex.Replace(bare_mac, ".{4}", "${0}:")).TrimEnd(':');

            Console.WriteLine(ipv6);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not `XOR` the first octet, but `OR` the first octet because the U/L bit must be set. This is explained in [RFC 4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture, Appendix A: Creating Modified EUI-64 Format Interface Identifiers](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#page-20) that show the U/L bit needs to be set to `1` to show a locally derived EUI-64 address.

Comment: I think you want to insert "fffe" at [index 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8), right?

Answer (score 1):

Excel Formula:

```
=CONCAT("fe80::",LOWER(DEC2HEX(BITXOR(HEX2DEC(LEFT(A1,2)),2),2)),MID(A1,4,5),"ff:fe",MID(A1,10,5),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on Golang:

```
func mac2ip(s string) (net.IP, error) {
    mac, err := net.ParseMAC(s)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Invert the bit at the index 6 (counting from 0)
    mac[0] ^= (1 << (2 - 1))

    ip := []byte{
        0xfe, 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, // prepend with fe80::
        mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], 0xff, 0xfe, mac[3], mac[4], mac[5], // insert ff:fe in the middle
    }

    return ip, nil
}
```

Full version: https://gist.github.com/0xef53/cb1c5d7594683982ba41d303ac03e9a0

Answer (score 0):

Fix for MAC adresses starting with "00"
string new_first_octet_hex = new_first_octet.ToString("X2");

Comment: This question was not about any particular programming language, thus you cannot respond with any code that does it.

You can look at the tags which and if they use programming to do so

Answer (score 0):

Excel formula in German for MAC address in cell "A1":

`=KLEIN(VERKETTEN("fe80::",KLEIN(DEZINHEX(BITXODER(HEXINDEZ(LINKS(A1,2)),2),2)),TEIL(A1,4,5),"ff:fe",TEIL(A1,10,5),RECHTS(A1,2)))`

I added "KLEIN" ("LOWER" in German) in front as the original formula mentioned above didn't convert the whole string to lower letters for me.